# can't show reminder data in a list view

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The app struggles to take the information from the Firebase Realtime Database and put it via an adapter to the ListView that is used on the main page(where all the reminders are shown). Note: The information that suppose to be shown to a user is unique to him (UID and key).

[image: Realtime database example]

```
public class ReminderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Reminder> {
    private Context context;
    private int resource;
    private ArrayList<Reminder> remindersList;

    public ReminderAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Reminder> remindersList) {
        super(context, resource, remindersList);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.remindersList = remindersList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resource, parent, false);
        }

        TextView reminderTitle = convertView.findViewById(R.id.aTitle);
        TextView reminderdate = convertView.findViewById(R.id.aDate);
        TextView reminderTime = convertView.findViewById(R.id.aTime);

        Reminder reminder = remindersList.get(position);

        reminderTitle.setText(reminder.getTitle());
        reminderdate.setText(reminder.getDate());
        reminderTime.setText(reminder.getTime());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

```
public class Reminder {
    String time;
    String title;
    String date;
    String uid;
    String key;

    public Reminder() {
        // Empty constructor required for Firebase
    }

    public Reminder(String title, String date, String time, String uid, String key) {
        this.title = title;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.uid = uid;
        this.key = key;
    }
    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
       this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

```
public class MainPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseAuth mauth;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    ArrayList<Reminder> Reminderslist;
    ArrayAdapter ReminderAdapter;
    ListView mrlv;
    private DatabaseReference database;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page);

        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        database = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Reminder");
        database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Reminderslist.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Reminder reminder = postSnapshot.getValue(Reminder.class);
                    Reminderslist.add(reminder);
                }
                ReminderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        mrlv = findViewById(R.id.mrv);
        Reminderslist = new ArrayList<Reminder>();
        ReminderAdapter = new ReminderAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 0, 0, Reminderslist);
        mrlv.setAdapter(ReminderAdapter);
        mrlv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Reminder reminder = Reminderslist.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainPageActivity.this, EditActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("key", reminder.key);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_top, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.mmadd) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SaveActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I mostly tried tutorials and ChatGPT however, without luck.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that reads data from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, stop ignoring errors. At a minimum, you should add inside `onCancelled`:

```
Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
```

Besides that, the problem in your code lies in the fact that you're using an incorrect reference to read the data. You say that:

> Note: the information that's supposed to be shown to a user is unique to him (UID and key)

But you're creating a reference that points to the `Reminder` node. To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
database = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Reminder");
```

Into:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
database = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Reminder").child(uid);
//
```

Now, the `database` points exactly to the node that belongs to the authenticated user.